# NSMutableArray of NSMutableDictionary does not show the data

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I created a class method but it does not show the data.

It shows null value in console when I do:

```
NSLog(@"full and array data :- %@",[array ObjectAtIndex:0]);
```

The 'dictionary' (it is a object of NSMutableDictionary) shows the data but when I added this object into the 'array' (it is an object of NSMutableArray) by using this:

```
[array addObject:dict];
```

after this line when I print the value (using `NSLog(@"array data :- %@",[array objectAtIndex:0] );`) of array it shows me the 'null' value.

```
+(NSMutableArray *)showAllDetail:(NSString *)query{    
    sqlite3 *stmnt;
    NSMutableArray *array;
    NSString *databasepath=[database getDatabasePath];
    if (sqlite3_open([databasepath UTF8String], &stmnt)) {
        NSLog(@"database not open......");
    }
    else{

        const char *queryStmt=[query UTF8String];
        sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(stmnt, queryStmt, -1, &stmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            while (sqlite3_step(stmt)==SQLITE_ROW) {
                 NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                const char *text;


                text=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(stmt,1);
                //NSLog(@"text :- %s",text);
                if (text!=NULL) {
                    [dictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:text] forKey:@"id"];

                 //NSLog(@"dictionary with id : - %@",dictionary);
                }

                text=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(stmt,2);
                if (text!=NULL) {
                    [dictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:text] forKey:@"name"];
                    // NSLog(@"dictionary with name : - %@",dictionary);
                }

                text=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(stmt,3);
                if (text!=NULL) {
                    [dictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:text] forKey:@"dob"];
                    // NSLog(@"dictionary with dob: - %@",dictionary);
                }


                NSLog(@"in the dic :- %s",text);
                 NSLog(@"dictionary data :- %@",dictionary);
              //------------------------------------------------ 
              //---------this show the result data dictionary --
              //------------------------------------------------ 
                [array addObject:dict];
                NSLog(@"array data :- %@",[array objectAtIndex:0] );
              //------------------------------------------------------------ 
              //---------this show the result :- "full and array data :- null"
              //---------------------------------------------------------------
               dict=nil;
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
        if ([array count]>0) {
            return array ;
        }
        else
            return nil;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

My output is:-

```
2013-10-29 17:30:32.644 myCRUD[1231:a0b] dictionary data :- {
    id = 1;
    name = naresh;
    dob = "10/10/1990";

     } 
2013-10-29 17:30:32.645 myCRUD[1231:a0b] array data :- (null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to create an array

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
```